# Symfony2 security: Multiple providers

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I have 2 bundles in my project:

- src/Korea/AlmacenBundle
- src/Galvez/RepuestosBundle

Each with their own database

- korea_motos -> AlmacenBundle
- galvez_motos -> RepuestosBundle

Actually my security.yml has only one provider:

```
providers:
    korea:
        entity: { class: Korea\AlmacenBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: username }
```

As you can see, both bundles are authenticated by the same table: Usuario, in korea_motos

TABLE: Usuario (korea_motos database)

## --ID--|----USERNAME----|---------BUNDLE---

-----1-----|-------------admin----------------|----------AlmacenBundle----------

-----2-----|-------------admin----------------|----------RepuestosBundle-------

Now i want to validate the users, for RepuestosBundle with a table Usuario in galvez_motos, removing the column "bundle" in the previous table.

The problem is in the security.yml file. If i make this:

```
providers:
    korea:
        entity: { class: Korea\AlmacenBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: username }
    galvez:
        entity: { class: Galvez\RepuestosBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: username }
```

Symfony launch a exception:

```
The class 'Galvez\RepuestosBundle\Entity\Usuario' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Korea\AlmacenBundle\Entity
```

Im trying to use 2 providers, one table per each bundle.. is this possible?

Files:
security.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
secure_all_services: false
expressions: true
```

security:
    encoders:
        Korea\AlmacenBundle\Entity\Usuario:
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1
        Galvez\RepuestosBundle\Entity\Usuario:
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    korea:
        entity: { class: Korea\AlmacenBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: username }
    galvez:
        entity: { class: Galvez\RepuestosBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        access_denied_handler: accessdenied_handler
        form_login:
            login_path:  /login
            check_path:  /login_check
            default_target_path: /redirect
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /login
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/redirect, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/galvez, roles: ROLE_ADMIN_GALVEZ }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN_KOREA }
```

config.yml -- can't copy/paste all :(

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection:   default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            charset:  UTF8
        galvez:
            driver:   %database_driver%
            dbname:   %database_name2%
            user:     %database_user2%
            password: %database_password2%
            host:     %database_host%
            port:     %database_port%
            charset:  UTF8
orm:
    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                AlmacenBundle: ~
        galvez:
            connection:       galvez
            mappings:
                RepuestosBundle: ~
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: localhost
database_port: null
database_name: korea_motos
database_user: root
database_password:
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: localhost
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: 5f7ac4e7c2b38d6dbe55a1f05bee2b02
database_path: null

database_name2: galvez_motos
database_user2: root
database_password2:
```

PD: Sry for my english :S

Answer (score 11):

Old question but for anyone looking for a solution, the manual explains it all [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_user_providers.html).
Basically, you need to chain your providers like this:

```yaml
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [korea, galvez]
        korea:
            entity: { class: Korea\AlmacenBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: username }
        galvez:
            entity: { class: Galvez\RepuestosBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: username }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with namespaces of your classes. Check if class `Galvez\RepuestosBundle\Entity\Usuario` is in the right namespace and if configuration is correct - maybe you accidentally left some copy-and-paste code from the other entity.

Try to persist both of these entities and fetch them (without security context) - I think you'll find your issue there.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with both entities:

## abcController.php

```
$em= $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('galvez');

$usuario_g = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('RepuestosBundle:Usuario', 'galvez')->find(1);
$usuario_g->setUsername('asdasd');
$em->persist($usuario_g);
$em->flush();
```

Works fine, but if i use

> $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

instead of

> $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('galvez');

When i try to flush, Symfony launchs the same error:

```
The class 'Galvez\RepuestosBundle\Entity\Usuario' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Korea\AlmacenBundle\Entity
```

Usuario.php (AlmacenBundle)

```
<?php

namespace Korea\AlmacenBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Usuario
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Korea\AlmacenBundle\Entity\UsuarioRepository")
 */
class Usuario implements UserInterface
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $salt;
```

Usuario.php (RepuestosBundle)

```
<?php

namespace Galvez\RepuestosBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Usuario
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Galvez\RepuestosBundle\Entity\UsuarioRepository")
*/
class Usuario implements UserInterface
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $salt;
```

## PD: Well, i think it's not possible, if i change this:

> default_connection:   korea

to:

> default_connection:   galvez

Symfony says:

```
MappingException: The class 'Korea\AlmacenBundle\Entity\Usuario' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Galvez\RepuestosBundle\Entity
```

the same error, but in reverse..

It seems like the monolog validation take the default connection (korea in this case) for search and validate