# Multiple firewalls "/admin/login_check" unable to find

Tags: security, symfony, routes, firewall

I have a problem with security configuration in Symfony2. I have two entities: `Admins` and `Users`.

I am following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910731/multiple-firewalls-with-symfony2) but always got a `"admin/login_check" unable to find` exception.

Thank you!

**security.yml**

```
security:   
    encoders:
        entity_admin:
            class: MyBundle\Entity\AdminUser
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 5000
            encode_as_base64: false
        entity_members:
            class: MyBundle\Entity\User
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 1000
            encode_as_base64: false

    providers:
        entity_admin:
            entity:
                class: Mdv\CommonBundle\Entity\Administrator
                property: username
        entity_members:
            entity:
                class: Mdv\CommonBundle\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin_secured_area:
            pattern: ^/admin
            provider: entity_admin
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /admin/login
                check_path: /admin/login_check
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin/

        members_secured_area:
            pattern: ^/user
            provider: entity_members
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /user/login_check
                login_path: /user/login
            logout:
                path:   /user/logout
                target: /user/

    access_control:
        admin_login:
            path: /admin/login
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        admin_area:
            path: ^/admin
            roles: ROLE_ADMIN
        members_login:
            path: /user/login
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        members_register:
            path: /user/register
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        members_area:
            path: ^/user
            roles: ROLE_USER
```

**routing.yml**

```
admin_administrator:
    resource: @MdvAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/administrator.yml
    prefix: /admin
```

**administrator.yml**

```
admin_login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: MdvAdminBundle:Administrator:login }
admin_login_check:
    pattern: /login_check
admin_logout:
    pattern: /logout
```

Comment: You need to **chain providers** when declaring multiple ones. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22664847/2150138)

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/22375113/251735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I solved it the following way:

```
    firewalls:
        ...
        login:         #add a firewall for the login who accepts anonymous
            pattern: ^/(admin/login|user/register)$ #it will accept one of the two chains given
            anonymous: true

        admin_secured_area:
            pattern: ^/           #remove the 'admin' it will be defined in the 'access_control'
            provider: entity_admin
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /admin/login
                check_path: /admin/login_check
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin/

        #remove the 'members_secured_area' it will be defined in the 'access_control'

    access_control:
        admin_login:
            path: /admin/login
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        admin_area:
            path: ^/admin
            roles: ROLE_ADMIN
        members_register:
            path: /user/register
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        members_area:
            path: ^/user
            roles: ROLE_USER
```

The `admin/login` and `user/login` could be the same, because they come from the same object `User` but they have different roles.