# check_path not found with multiple firewalls in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to setup a backend and frontend firewall system in Symfony 2. I have two login forms, one for the frontend and another one for the admin control panel. Different providers and so on. My configuration looks like this:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        backend:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            anonymous:  true
            provider:   admin_users
            form_login:
                login_path: /admin/login
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                default_target_path: /admin

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            provider:   normal_users
            anonymous:  true
            form_login: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

And my routing.yml:

```
login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: MyFrontendBundle:Default:login }

login_check:
    path:     /login_check

admin_login:
    path:     /admin/login
    defaults: { _controller: MyBackendBundle:Default:login }

admin_login_check:
    path:     /admin/login_check
```

Seems right, but i'm having the following error: Unable to find the controller for path "/admin/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration

Any ideas? :)

Comment: I guess your pattern should be `pattern:    ^/admin.*`

Comment: Does this route appear in `app/console router:debug`?

Comment: If you use this pattern for your backend firewall : `pattern: /admin/.*`

Comment: No, the pattern does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: I had similar issue when I was trying to use firewalls with overlapping url pattern and the first firewall did not have check_path ( I was using http_basic in first firewall) and second using form_login. Your url mapping seems to be right, please check if you have correct check_path (/admin/login_check) in your admin controller.

Comment: you got problem solved?

Comment: Not really. Still not able to use a proper login form

Answer (score 2):

This solution I use in my projects. Hope this will work with two login forms too.

Add stub for controller

```
admin_login_check:
    path:     /admin/login_check
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:adminLoginCheck }
```

Action stub. This action will never be reached, but "controller not found" error will gone.

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
public function adminLoginCheckAction()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_login'));
}
```

Comment: The problem is... the action is actually reached.

Comment: @vinnylinux Could you update your question with step by step instruction how to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Just use the AcmeDemoBundle and add the second firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Your url mapping seems to be right,

Please check if you have correct `check_path (/admin/login_check)` in your admin controller.

or

Try adding login_check under access_control as below,

```
- { path: ^/admin/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I had similar issue when I was trying to use firewalls with overlapping url patterns. The first firewall did not have check_path ( I was using http_basic in first firewall) and in second firwall I was using form_login. I had to change URL mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Might not be bad just to remove the "/" so you only have :

```
login_path: admin/login
check_path: admin/login_check
default_target_path: admin
```

And let the pattern attribute the way it is. This is actually how my `security.yml` looks like and would explain the route problem.